# Mod Coder Pack Minecraft: How can I detect if a Mouse Button is pressed?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm making my own Minecraft Client with the MCP (Mod Coder Pack).

But I don't know how can I detect, for example, in a update method if a mouse button is pressed and which.

I'm using the MCP 9.10 (Minecraft 1.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This series helped me:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGEImsH6md6OH7nuLgbsTEzN0F1qN3KLy

and on the `OnPreUpdate` method, you can do something like

```
public void onPreUpdate() {
        if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
            
        }
    }
```